# Cannot get matched row from model in yii

Tags: javascript, php, json, yii, yii2

I'm trying to get the related row from user input that is using select2. I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZ-6huMYxBc&t=1076s) tutorial on how to do it but right now I'm stuck at getting the matched row.
This is the select2 to get the input from user :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'kod_bangunan')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(
                        KodModal::find()
                            ->select('kod_bangunan, kod_bangunan')
                            ->where(['aktif' => 'Y'])
                            ->asArray()
                            ->all(), 'kod_bangunan', 'kod_bangunan'
                        ),
                    'language' => 'en',
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => '-- PLEASE SELECT --', 'class' => 'form-control'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'allowClear' => true,
                        'initialize' => true,
                    ],
                ]);

            ?>
```

So kod_bangunan is the id that I want the user select from. KodModal is the model for my database kod_modal.

And this is my javascript, I put it at the same file as the above code which is in _capital.php
the path is

> backend/views/capital-setting/_capital.php

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS
//here right all javascript 

$('#kodmodal-kod_bangunan').change(function(){
   //kod_bangunan holds the value that is the building code selected
   var kod_bangunan = $(this).val();
   $.get('index.php?r=capitalsetting/get-for-building',{ kod_bangunan : kod_bangunan }, function(data){
       alert(data);
   });
});

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

and this is my controller file which is CapitalSettingController.php
the path is

> backend/controllers/CapitalSettingController.php

```
public function actionGetForBuilding($kod_bangunan){
    $KodModal = KodModal::findOne(['kod_bangunan'=>$kod_bangunan]);
    echo Json::encode($KodModal);
}
```

so when I choose one kod bangunan from the select2 it suppose to alert the data from row that is matched with kod_bangunan. but right now it shows me error on the console. Here is the error screenshot [image]

Please help, I'm new in Yii framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you check why your developer tool shows following request uri?

capital-setting/index.php?r=kod_modal/capitalsetting/get-for-building&kod_bangunan=008

i think this should look like:

capital-setting/get-for-building?kod_bangunan=008

so try to create the url with yii method:

```
$url = Url::to(['capital-setting/get-for-building']);
<?php
$script = <<< JS
//here right all javascript 

$('#kodmodal-kod_bangunan').change(function(){
   //kod_bangunan holds the value that is the building code selected
   var kod_bangunan = $(this).val();
   $.get('$url',{ kod_bangunan : kod_bangunan }, function(data){
       alert(data);
   });
});

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

2. option is use pjax

in your view:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'kod_bangunan')->widget(Select2::class, [
    ...
    'pluginEvents' => [
        "select2:select" => <<<JS
function onSelect() {
    $.pjax({
    type: 'POST',
    container: '#partial-form-pjax',
    data: $('form').serialize()
    })
}
JS
        ,
    ],
]); ?>


<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'partial-form-pjax']) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'building_kod')->textInput(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'name_building')->textInput(); ?>

<?php Pjax::end() ?>
```

in your controller:

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isPjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $KodModal = KodModal::findOne(['kod_bangunan'=>$kod_bangunan]);
    $model->kod_building = $KodModal->kod_building;
    $model->name_building = $KodModal->name_building;
    return $this->render('[same view]', compact('model'));
}
```

Comment: Opps sorry I took that screenshot when i set `$.get('index.php?r=KodModal/capitalsetting/get-for-building',{ kod_bangunan : kod_bangunan }, function(data){` in the _capital.php I thought it would solve the problems. Thanks for your answers, I tried option 1 and it says $url is undefined. Is the `$url = Url::to(['capital-setting/get-for-building']);` suppose to be outside of <?php?> ? I don't quite understand your option 2 though, for the controller code do I just need to replace my function actionGetForBuilding?

Comment: Update I got it! I didn't add use yii\helpers\Url; at the top thanks for the answer though! it gives me some hint